# My ubuntu VM does not recognize my device in 'adb devices'

Tags: android, ubuntu

I'm trying to run `'adb devices'` and see my device in VM.
Currently, all I have got is an empty list of connected devices.

The `'usb debbuging'` mode is enabled in my device, and I'm developing.
On Windows, when I do `'adb devices'` I can see the device.

I have already tried to kill and start the server-> doesn't work for me.
I have tried also

```
" autossh -nNL5037:localhost:5037 -oExitOnForwardFailure=yes 10.0.2.2" but I have got 'connection refused'.
```

Why I can't see it in the VM? Am I miss something??

I will be grand full for any help..

Comment: Do you see your device in `Nautilus`?

Comment: No, i just see the device in my Windows OS, but not in ubuntu VM.

Comment: Probably an issue with forwarding the USB into the VM. In Ubuntu (as a host system) you have to install some extras for virtual box, don't know how it works in Windows.